# Looping though array and putting values as object keys in reverse order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

So I have two scenarios, one where the array looks like ["20, "21", "22", "23", "24"] and I'm able to successfully loop through the array to create an object with each array value is the object key (i.e. {"20": [],"21": [],"22": [],"23": [],"24": []}). This is working as intended. The problem occurs when I have an array like ["24", "23", "22", "21", "20"], and when this is looped over, it creates an object exactly like the first scenario {"20": [],"21": [],"22": [],"23": [],"24": []}, when I need it to be {"24": [],"23": [],"22": [],"21": [],"20": []}. I have no clue what could be going on as I've read that javascript objects maintain their order

```
let numberObject = {};

["20", "21", "22", "23", "24"].forEach((date) => {
numberObject[date] = [];
});

Output: {"20": [],"21": [],"22": [],"23": [],"24": []}
```

---

```
let numberObject = {};

["24", "23", "22", "21", "20"].forEach((date) => {
numberObject[date] = [];
});

Output: {"20": [],"21": [],"22": [],"23": [],"24": []}
Expected output: {"24": [],"23": [],"22": [],"21": [],"20": []}
```

Any idea why the expected output isn't occurring?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: If you want to specifically control the order, don't use an object with properties, use an array.  Arrays are for ordered collections, objects are not.